# GTK Widget for volume control bar

Tags: widget, controls, gtk, volume

I want this kind of volume control bar shown in image. Is there any GtkWidget or separate package i can download and run? I've already searched but didn't found anything.
I was thinking about using it on polybar, like on Windows, when you click the volume icon and the volume control bar pops-up. Also, it would be nice the bar didn't had that little protrusion below, as i use the bar in the top of the screen but it doesn't necessarily needs to, any bar similar to this one would fit.

Thanks,
Erick César

[image: GTK Volume Control]

Answer (score 0):

Here it is: [GtkVolumeButton](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkVolumeButton.html) :)